# Charset Conversion € \x80

Tags: javascript, char, hex, ascii, utf

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious here but I have a string that at a certain point has the `€` and I know that this means the next section repeats 128 times or if the character is `7` then it repeats 55 times.

So a basic function would be like such :

```js
function GetMultiplier(str){ 
    var M = (/XXX(.)/g).exec(str)[1]; // Where the separator is 'XXX' for example
    if(M=="€") return 128; 
    else if(M=="7") return 55; 
    else return undefined; 
}; 

GetMultiplier('abc123XXX€helloworld'); \\ Would return 128
```

So basically I need this but no mater what comes after the separator it will return a numeric value.

[HERE](https://www.charset.org/utf-8) is the link to the charsets that I'm using to manually decode this.

Sorry for the bad explanation.

Comment: Is there are reason why you want `€` to map to control character of `128`? As described in that link, the mapping of `€` to `128` is a specific character set mapping used by Windows-1252. There are other mappings that exist that don't have this same mapping (eg: [ISO-8859-1 (Western Europe)](https://www.charset.org/charsets/iso-8859-1)) for this control character (ie: 128 maps to nothing). The more accurate value for `€` would be [8364](https://www.charset.org/utf-8/9)

Comment: Is there a way to reverse a character to Windows-1252 mapping?

Comment: That'd most likely require some custom logic, or a library of some sort. If you can work with `8364` though then `'€'.charCodeAt(0)` would give you that. `'7'.charCodeAt(0)` gives `55` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use `match` instead of `exec` and drop the `/g`:

```js
function GetMultiplier(str){ 
    var M = str.match(/XXX(.)/)[1];
    if(M=="€") return 128; 
    else if(M=="7") return 55; 
    else return undefined; 
}; 

a = GetMultiplier('abc123XXX€helloworld'); 
console.log(a)
```